# Unable to Knit to PDF in R Notebook due to a library?

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr

I am using the dplyr library to allow for piping (%>%) commands together - for example:

```
    Q1 <- 
    select(TDBRnew, nhs_england_region, new_deaths_total)%>%
    group_by(nhs_england_region)%>%
    mutate (sum(new_deaths_total))%>%
    rename(Total_Deaths = "sum(new_deaths_total)")%>%
    arrange(Total_Deaths)%>%
    select(-c(new_deaths_total))


Q1DF <- unique(Q1)
Q1DF
```

All the code runs correctly but when I try knitting to a pdf, the compiler spits out this error:

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUjnr.png)

In addition to this error, It also mentions a lack of pdfcrop, which after a fair bit of research is part of "...TeX" libraries, which as far as I can see are installed.

[My RStudio window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yw35.png) You can see dplyr is built and working - I have been banging my head against dozens of posts with kitting problems and have yet to come across one specifically like this.

Comment: knit a document that just lists your loaded namespaces: `data.frame( package = loadedNamespaces() ` , then you will see if they are there as you have reason to believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been using install.packages() to prompt them into the knit and not library().

Once I listed all the appropriate libraries using (e.g.) library(dplyr) it worked immediately. After reading through dozens of problems for hours, somehow this just isn't one I came across so, hopefully it helps someone.